# Installation failure on second m.2 SSD with AMD 3900x and Asus ROG Strix X570 motherboard

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, usb, ssd, windows-10

My new hardware:

- AMD 3900x
- ASUS ROG Strix X570-E Gaming ATX Motherboard with PCIe 4.0, Aura Sync
- GIGABYTES GPU RTX 2070 Super Gaming OC 8G
- first m.2 nvme SSD 970 EVO plus 500GB (Windows 10 pro installed)
- second m.2 nvme SSD 970 EVO plus 500GB (Ubuntu supposed to be here)
- normal 5400 RPM laptop HDD 1000GB (Data Drive connected in SATA 6G, used as system backup drive, installed after windows 10 installed)

My procedure:

1. Make bootable USB stick (which worked on my old laptop machine)
2. Disable Desktop fastboot, secureboot in BIOS, choose USB to boot from

My problem:

The boot seems okay first, Ubuntu menu shows up, and when I select try Ubuntu or install Ubuntu on hard drive, the same thing happens each time I try to do so. The screen froze immediately. No matter what key I press, the screen is the same(frozen). I have to press the power button for 10 seconds to force shutdown.

Installing Ubuntu from USB stick:

[image: install Ubuntu from USB stick]

Installing Fedora from USB stick:

[image: install Fedora from USB stick]

Motherboard supports two m.2 SSD slots:

[image: motherboard supports two m.2 SSD slots]

Update:
ACPI off and nomodeset at try Ubuntu, press e.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try adding the "nomodeset acpi=no"  keywords to the grub line starting with "linux" at the "quiet splash" words. You will need to refine the acpi after you boot. Did you update your firmware?

Comment: yeah the BIOS driver is brand new, I can't type anything, there is even no grub console show up before it gets frozen

Comment: Are you installing 19.04  as AMD fix to UEFI only mentions 19.04. AMD UEFI/BIOS update for Ryzen 3000 series
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ryzen-3000-BIOS-Update-Good
AMD Releases BIOS Fix To Motherboard Partners For Booting Newer Linux Distributions July 2019
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMD-Releases-Linux-Zen2-Fix

Comment: Please post the output of sudo inxi -FxxxmzA  in your original question.  At the "Try Ubuntu", type "e" to edit, (instructions at bottom of page). add to the linux line and f10 to boot.

Comment: @oldfred no I was installing ubuntu 18.04 LTS. in UEFI mode,  using Rufus.exe to make a bootable USB,

Comment: AMD says fix is only for 19.04. While I normally recommend using an LTS version, you may need 19.04 or even try 19.10 as the daily updated version is working for me. I do use 18.04 as my main working install.

Comment: @ubfan1 I did what you suggest, and I found the related articles on the internet talking about the same operations. unfortunately, it won't work, as for sudo inxi..

Comment: in your bios settings is the boot set to uefi or legacy ?

Comment: @Yvain uefi no more legacy in new build pc

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Ubfan1.
The solution in my case is:

1. Reboot into try Ubuntu grub interface and press e to enter console.
2. Append nomodeset right after quiet splash  no acpi = no added.
3. Reboot into Ubuntu again, manually partition the second m.2 nvme SSD (choose something else).
4. Notice to choose bootloader to be installed on this second m.2 SSD, while the Windows 10 installation on the first m.2 SSD, and the Windows boot manager is on the third disk (1000G HDD, I don't know why it is here, I attached the disk to the system only after I successfully installed Windows 10).
5. Find the right Nvidia driver online and install it.
6. Reboot.

It took me many hours try and error. Finally it worked.